# statsmodels import error. Is there an alternative to statsmodels MSTL?

Tags: python, statsmodels

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL
```

same error on two computers:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'MSTL' from 'statsmodels.tsa.seasonal'.
```

One computer Ubuntu 20.04, the second Windows11. Updates on both systems.

try to:

- `pip3 install statsmodels==0.13`
- `pip3 install statsmodels==0.12.2`

same problem

Need MSTL. Maybe there is an alternative statsmodels? Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? See this section of the API docs https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html#multivariate-time-series-models

Comment: 1. pip3 install statsmodels It is OK 2. In cmd jupiter-lab 3. in jupyter: from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'MSTL' from 'statsmodels.tsa' (c:\users\glukv\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\__init__.py)

Comment: You are right, there is no MSTL in the documentation, but there is STL. Thanks